# &nbsp; to space not getting converted in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The following code simply replace " " to empty space and then compare the resulted string with the actual text but the result always comes "Not Equal" because the variable text always takes one space after replace function call. The console log shows same value for text and content; but at the time of comparison it gives false

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>

    <p id="result"></p>
    <br><br>

    <p id="html"></p>
    <br>
    <p id="content"></p>

    <script>

        var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit&nbsp;&nbsp; amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tortor risus, pharetra eu laoreet at, rhoncus quis ipsum. Mauris dictum orci sed libero pretium sollicitudin".replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ');

        var content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit   amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tortor risus, pharetra eu laoreet at, rhoncus quis ipsum. Mauris dictum orci sed libero pretium sollicitudin";

        console.log(text);
        console.log(content);

        var result = "";
        if (text == content) {
            result = "Equal";
        } else {
            result = "Not Equal";
        }

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result; 
        document.getElementById("html").innerHTML = text;
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = content;

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in string you use `&nbsp;` it is parsed literally as those characters. Instead if you want a non-breaking space, you should use `\xa0` character, which is a non-breaking space character.

Comment: Thanks a lot; this one worked for me. Now I am using it as replace(/&nbsp;/gi, '\xa0');

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this `.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ');` after declaring your text variable. Istead, do it here

```
var result = "";
if (text.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ') == content) {
    result = "Equal";
} else {
     result = "Not Equal";
}
```